# Not sure how to print this?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to modify code that I've written for an assignment:

```
public class ToweringStrings2 {

    public static final int H = 2; //constant for the tower

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawTowers(H);
    }

    public static void drawTowers(int H) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= H; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("+");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= H + 2; k++) {
            System.out.print("@");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

so that it prints sequential numbers starting at 1, instead of +s. Currently, it prints:

[image]

This is what the new code is supposed to print:
[image]

and so on.

For some reason I'm just really stuck and can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you please provide an example output?

Comment: Create a variable ``i`` of type ``int`` above your loop and set it to ``1``. Then, instead of using ``System.out.print("+");``, use ``System.out.print(i++);``.

Comment: Where is defined constant for the tower count or tower count is always 3?

Comment: @Vlad "probably" not. That would start the 3rd line with a 3, not a 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extra variable to print and increment

Like that:

```
public class ToweringStrings2 {
    public static final int H = 10; //constant for the tower

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawTowers(H);
    }

    public static void drawTowers(int H) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= H; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(count++ + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= H + 2; k++) {
            System.out.print("@ ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, it definitely did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** - make it print a variable rather than a hard-coded string. Instead of `System.out.print("+")`, `System.out.print(counter)`.

For this to work you need to have declared `counter` somewhere in the same scope as the statement: `int counter = 0`.

Run this. You'll see it print "0" where it used to print "+".

**Step 2** - Now you need to make `counter` increase by one every time it prints.

Find the right place to add:

```
 counter = counter + 1;
```

Run it and see it work.

**Further notes**

A more concise alternative to `var = var + 1` is `var++`.

You can even do this at the same time as you use the value of a variable:

```
 System.out.println(var++);
```

This can be used to express some algorithms very concisely -- but it can be confusing for beginners, so feel free to not use this technique until you're comfortable with the basics.